# mongo sort_key_generator stage though there is a proper index

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing

I am executing a simple query + sort operation in my Mongo v4.x.

```
db.USERS.find({"A" : "value", "B" : "valueB", "C" : "valueC"}).sort({"D" : -1});
```

with the following index to support the query

```
db.USERS.createIndex({"A" : 1, "B" : 1, "C" : 1, "D" : -1})
```

Explain - winning plans show -

```
IXSCAN - FETCH - SORT_KEY_GENERATOR - SORT
```

**It appears that the IXSCAN did use the index to fetch the documents, but not to sort them?
(as SORT_KEY_GENERATOR means in-memory sorting)**

Would you have any suggestions as to why my index is not supporting the query? thanks!

Comment: As per the documentation the _sort_ operation should be using the index ([Sort and Non-Prefix Subset of Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/index.html#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index)). Why its not using the index? No idea, based upon what you have posted.

Comment: @prasad_ indeed. any other details I can share here to figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Did the explain output for the IXSCAN indicate any multikey paths?